# " error: ‘remap’ is not a member of ‘cv’ " when using python setup.py install

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv, installation

I am trying to install a face tracker for Python on Ubuntu through the terminal. I installed from here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFaceTracker/0.1.1

And used the linux version of setup.py from here:
http://reidmayo.com/2014/07/15/how-to-install-pyfacetracker-on-linux-fedora-19/

But when I tried to type in "sudo python setup.py install" while inside the directory of the package, it ended up giving me this error:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pyFaceTracker.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pyFaceTracker.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pyFaceTracker.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pyFaceTracker.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pyFaceTracker.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'facetracker._facetracker' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Iexternal/FaceTracker/include -I/usr/include/opencv2/core -I/usr/include/opencv2/imgproc -I/usr/include/opencv2/video -I/usr/include/opencv2/features2d -I/usr/include/opencv2/flann -I/usr/include/opencv2/calib3d -I/usr/include/opencv2/objdetect -I/usr/include/opencv2/legacy -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PDM.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PDM.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PDM.cc: In member function ‘void FACETRACKER::PDM::CalcRigidJacob(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)’:
external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PDM.cc:234:23: warning: unused variable ‘m’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int i,n = _M.rows/3,m = _V.cols; double X,Y,Z;
                       ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Iexternal/FaceTracker/include -I/usr/include/opencv2/core -I/usr/include/opencv2/imgproc -I/usr/include/opencv2/video -I/usr/include/opencv2/features2d -I/usr/include/opencv2/flann -I/usr/include/opencv2/calib3d -I/usr/include/opencv2/objdetect -I/usr/include/opencv2/legacy -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PAW.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PAW.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PAW.cc: In member function ‘void FACETRACKER::PAW::Crop(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)’:
external/FaceTracker/src/lib/PAW.cc:167:3: error: ‘remap’ is not a member of ‘cv’
   cv::remap(src,dst,_mapx,_mapy,CV_INTER_LINEAR); return;
   ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

If it helps, I am using OpenCV 3.0.0 alpha for C++ and OpenCV 3.0.0 beta for python.

How would I fix something like this?

Comment: try to make it `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` [here](https://bitbucket.org/amitibo/pyfacetracker/src/9a0bc8d8958074e9c0bf98f0cc3e1e99db9d37b4/src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp?at=default#cl-10)  , the old c-api headers(opencv/cv.h) do no more pull in the correct `opencv2/calib3d.hpp` headers

Comment: I tried replacing "<opencv/cv.h>" with "<opencv2/opencv.hpp>" in "_pyFaceTracker.cpp", but it still keeps giving me the same error: ‘remap’ is not a member of ‘cv’

Answer (score 0):

To make it find cv::remap, as @berak said, you have to make it include the opencv2/opencv.hpp, but not in _pyFaceTracker.cpp, you have to include it in [here](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker/blob/master/include/FaceTracker/IO.h#L42) (IO.h). IO.h is used in PAW.h and implements cv::remap function. After I've done this, I got rid of that error and stumbled upon another one regarding the helper functions. Any ideas here?

WARNING: Long log ahead! 
`

```
In file included from src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:20:0:
src/opencv_helpers.h:161:16: error: cannot declare variable ‘g_numpyAllocator’ to be of abstract type ‘NumpyAllocator’
 NumpyAllocator g_numpyAllocator;
                ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:111:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘NumpyAllocator’:
 class NumpyAllocator : public MatAllocator
       ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:59:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:46,
                 from external/FaceTracker/include/FaceTracker/IO.h:43,
                 from external/FaceTracker/include/FaceTracker/PDM.h:42,
                 from external/FaceTracker/include/FaceTracker/CLM.h:42,
                 from external/FaceTracker/include/FaceTracker/Tracker.h:42,
                 from src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:12:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:417:23: note:   virtual cv::UMatData* cv::MatAllocator::allocate(int, const int*, int, void*, size_t*, int, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const
     virtual UMatData* allocate(int dims, const int* sizes, int type,
                       ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:419:18: note:   virtual bool cv::MatAllocator::allocate(cv::UMatData*, int, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const
     virtual bool allocate(UMatData* data, int accessflags, UMatUsageFlags usage
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:420:18: note:   virtual void cv::MatAllocator::deallocate(cv::UMatData*) const
     virtual void deallocate(UMatData* data) const = 0;
                  ^
In file included from src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:20:0:
src/opencv_helpers.h: In function ‘int pyopencv_to(const PyObject*, cv::Mat&, const char*, bool)’:
src/opencv_helpers.h:241:11: error: ‘class cv::Mat’ has no member named ‘refcount’
         m.refcount = refcountFromPyObject(o);
           ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_from(const cv::Mat&)’:
src/opencv_helpers.h:262:12: error: ‘class cv::Mat’ has no member named ‘refcount’
     if(!p->refcount || p->allocator != &g_numpyAllocator)
            ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:269:36: error: ‘class cv::Mat’ has no member named ‘refcount’
     return pyObjectFromRefcount(p->refcount);
                                    ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: At global scope:
src/opencv_helpers.h:349:35: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
     static bool to(PyObject* obj, vector<_Tp>& value, const char* name="<unknow
                                   ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:349:41: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static bool to(PyObject* obj, vector<_Tp>& value, const char* name="<unknow
                                         ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:440:33: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
     static PyObject* from(const vector<_Tp>& value)
                                 ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:440:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     static PyObject* from(const vector<_Tp>& value)
                                       ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: In static member function ‘static bool pyopencvVecConverter<_Tp>::to(PyObject*, int)’:
src/opencv_helpers.h:357:33: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
             pyopencv_to(obj, m, name);
                                 ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:358:22: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
             m.copyTo(value);
                      ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:362:46: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
         PyObject *seq = PySequence_Fast(obj, name);
                                              ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:366:9: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
         value.resize(n);
         ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: In static member function ‘static PyObject* pyopencvVecConverter<_Tp>::from(int)’:
src/opencv_helpers.h:442:12: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
         if(value.empty())
            ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:444:22: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
         Mat src((int)value.size(), DataType<_Tp>::channels, DataType<_Tp>::dept
                      ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: At global scope:
src/opencv_helpers.h:450:70: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
 emplate<typename _Tp> static inline bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, vector<_Tp>
                                                                     ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:450:76: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 e<typename _Tp> static inline bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, vector<_Tp>& valu
                                                                     ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: In function ‘bool pyopencv_to(PyObject*, int)’:
src/opencv_helpers.h:452:47: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
     return pyopencvVecConverter<_Tp>::to(obj, value, name);
                                               ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:452:54: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
     return pyopencvVecConverter<_Tp>::to(obj, value, name);
                                                      ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: At global scope:
src/opencv_helpers.h:455:68: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 template<typename _Tp> static inline PyObject* pyopencv_from(const vector<_Tp>&
                                                                    ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:455:74: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 ate<typename _Tp> static inline PyObject* pyopencv_from(const vector<_Tp>& valu
                                                                     ^
src/opencv_helpers.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_from(int)’:
src/opencv_helpers.h:457:44: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
     return pyopencvVecConverter<_Tp>::from(value);
                                            ^
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp: In function ‘int FaceTracker_init(FaceTracker*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:91:43: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     static char *kwlist[] = {"fname", NULL};
                                           ^
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp: At global scope:
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 };
 ^
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:129:1: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* FaceTracker_setWindowSizes(FaceTracker*, PyObject*)’:
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:157:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘pyopencv_to(PyObject*&, std::vector<int>&)’
     if (!pyopencv_to<int>(sizes_array, self->window_sizes))
                                                          ^
In file included from src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:20:0:
src/opencv_helpers.h:450:43: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool pyopencv_to(PyObject*, int)
 template<typename _Tp> static inline bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, vector<_Tp
                                           ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:450:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:157:46: note:   cannot convert ‘self->FaceTracker::window_sizes’ (type ‘std::vector<int>’) to type ‘int’
     if (!pyopencv_to<int>(sizes_array, self->window_sizes))
                                              ^
In file included from src/_pyFaceTracker.cpp:20:0:
src/opencv_helpers.h: At global scope:
src/opencv_helpers.h:59:18: warning: ‘opencv_error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static PyObject* opencv_error = 0;
                  ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:272:13: warning: ‘bool pyopencv_to(PyObject*, cv::Scalar&, const char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static bool pyopencv_to(PyObject *o, Scalar& s, const char *name = "<unknown>")
             ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:311:18: warning: ‘PyObject* pyopencv_from(bool)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static PyObject* pyopencv_from(bool value)
                  ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:316:13: warning: ‘bool pyopencv_to(PyObject*, bool&, const char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, bool& value, const char* name = "<unknow
             ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:328:18: warning: ‘PyObject* pyopencv_from(size_t)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static PyObject* pyopencv_from(size_t value)
                  ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:333:13: warning: ‘bool pyopencv_to(PyObject*, size_t&, const char*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, size_t& value, const char* name = "<unkn
             ^
src/opencv_helpers.h:342:18: warning: ‘PyObject* pyopencv_from(int)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static PyObject* pyopencv_from(int value)
                  ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

`